# Action script 3.0 issue, my swf not unloading

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash

Having a little trouble with an Flash for iOS application! I have a button "start" which loads an external swf. Then I have a different button, "home", which should do three things:

1. unload the external swf
2. stop all sounds
3. return to frame 1

It all SEEMS to work, but then it appears that the SWF never unloads! I keep hearing it over and over again.

```
  //code on frame follows...mythbutt_home


 stop();

//home button

mythbutt_home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_4);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
removeChild(fl_ProLoader_3);

}
mythbutt_home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToStopAllSounds);

function fl_ClickToStopAllSounds(event:MouseEvent):void
{
SoundMixer.stopAll();
}

mythbutt_home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_1);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(1);
}


//start button

start_button_aboriginal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_3);

import fl.display.ProLoader;
var fl_ProLoader_3:ProLoader;

//This variable keeps track of whether you want to load or unload the SWF
var fl_ToLoad_3:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
if(fl_ToLoad_3)
{
    fl_ProLoader_3 = new ProLoader();
    fl_ProLoader_3.load(new URLRequest("myths/myth_aboriginal.swf"));
    addChild(fl_ProLoader_3);
    fl_ProLoader_3.x = 114;
    fl_ProLoader_3.y = 41;
 }
 else
 {
    fl_ProLoader_3.unload();
    removeChild(fl_ProLoader_3);
    fl_ProLoader_3 = null;
}
// Toggle whether you want to load or unload the SWF
fl_ToLoad_3 = !fl_ToLoad_3;
}
```

Comment: first, trace the swf after after you unloaded it, see if its there... im guessing the swf creates a new sound so if you remove the SWFthe sound is still there you will need probably to delete the sound too;

Comment: Maybe if you didn't decompile the code you might have a better understanding of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you shouldnt be doing this over multible Frames. It would be best to use external .as files.
To properly unload the swf you need to delete all refrences to the swf itself and objects in the swf. This includes EventListeners for which you should use a weak refference like this:

```
// params: eventName, listener, capturePhase, priority, useWeakReference
someObj.addEventListener("eventName",myFunct,false,0,true);
```

and use unloadAndStop(); and remove first!

```
removeChild(fl_ProLoader_3);
fl_ProLoader_3.unloadAndStop();
fl_ProLoader_3 = null;
```

And trace the loader after you null it, and see what the output says!

Comment: Hi - thanks so much for answering! I can't use external AS files, all code has to be on the main (parent) file. I have no code whatsoever in the child swf. You're saying I need to have all code for the whole parent on ONE frame, I assume frame 1?

Comment: And, those two snippets of code you sent; where would they go?

Comment: sorry, one more question (I am a beginner with AS3); I would replace "someObj" with what exactly? The child? the button name? And, I would replace "eventName" with what? Or does it stay like that?

Comment: its a scheme for your existing listeners. so t your listeners add the parameters `,false,0,false);
the block starting with removeChild replaces the one in your else statement

Comment: like this?

start_button_aboriginal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_3,false,0,true);

Comment: then you could accept answer ;) .. thats how this site works.
And yes, thats how its meant to be

Comment: Ah - it IS working!! I re-arranged the code a bit, and that did the trick. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: the only problem is the "unload swf when it's finished playing" bit, that's the last item. Would you still have time/patience for me?

Comment: sorry, I only see the "unload on click" info.