# unload external swf (child) from the main screen when it has reached last frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, parent-child

I have an external swf loading into a main frame (the URL request), and when the swf reaches it's final frame I need it to UNLOAD itself. I need to do this without any code on the CHILD swf, as this is for an iOS application. Can anyone help?

```
//start button

start_button_aboriginal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_3);

import fl.display.ProLoader;
var fl_ProLoader_3:ProLoader;

//This variable keeps track of whether you want to load or unload the SWF
var fl_ToLoad_3:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
if(fl_ToLoad_3)
{
    fl_ProLoader_3 = new ProLoader();
    fl_ProLoader_3.load(new URLRequest("myths/myth_aboriginal.swf"));
    addChild(fl_ProLoader_3);
    fl_ProLoader_3.x = 114;
    fl_ProLoader_3.y = 41;
}
else
{
    fl_ProLoader_3.unload();
    removeChild(fl_ProLoader_3);
    fl_ProLoader_3 = null;
}
// Toggle whether you want to load or unload the SWF
fl_ToLoad_3 = !fl_ToLoad_3;

//here, I want to UNLOAD the external SWF when it is finished playing.

var totFrames:Number=childMC.totalFrames;
var curFrame:Number;

childMC.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, remove);

    function remove(evt:Event):void {
    curFrame=childMC.currentFrame;
    if (totFrames==curFrame) {
        removeChild(childMC);
    }
}
```

Comment: First off you could react to your other similar qustion!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677907/action-script-3-0-issue-my-swf-not-unloading/15678538#15678538
and then you could tell us whats not working in the code! whats happening? any error messages?

Comment: and you have a function inside a function. write that second one outside

Comment: Thanks for your answer! they are two different questions - the errors I am getting relate to childMC; it seems I am not defining it. But I am loading an external swf, not a library item which can be named.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare childMC in a global scope and the assign the loader content.
and dont declare functions inside of functions!!

something like this **NOT TESTET**

```
import fl.display.Loader; // impoerts belong at the top

var fl_ProLoader_3:ProLoader; // then your global vars
var childMC:MovieClip; // instatiate childMC with global scope

start_button_aboriginal.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_3,false,0,false); // listener with weak refference

var fl_ToLoad_3:Boolean = true;

function fl_ClickToLoadUnloadSWF_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
if(fl_ToLoad_3)
{
    fl_ProLoader_3 = new Loader();
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myths/myth_aboriginal.swf"); 
    var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null); // IOS needs this
        fl_ProLoader_3.load(url, loaderContext);
    fl_ProLoader_3.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleteHandler,false,0,false);

}
else
{
    if(childMC){
            removeChild(childMC);
            childMC.unloadAndStop();
            childMC = null; 
    }

}
// Toggle whether you want to load or unload the SWF
fl_ToLoad_3 = !fl_ToLoad_3;

}
function loadCompleteHandler(evt:Event):void
{
        childMC = evt.target.content as MovieClip;
        childMC.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, remove);
        addChild(childMC);
        childMC.x = 114;
        childMC.y = 41;
}

function remove(evt:Event):void {
    var totFrames:Number=childMC.totalFrames;
    var curFrame:Number =childMC.currentFrame;;

    if (totFrames==curFrame) {
      childMC.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, remove);
      removeChild(childMC);
      childMC.unloadAndStop();
      childMC = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: oh here it is - I am getting the following error:
"Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 10, Line 94 1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions."

Comment: my bad. its a habit, i dont code on the timeline! delete the "private" from the loadCompleteHandler function

Comment: Now I am getting this:
"Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 60, Line 60 1172: Definition fl.display:Loader could not be found."

Comment: should "Loader" actually say "ProLoader" in this case, as I have defined it above?

Comment: No i used a normal loader! the import should be flash.display.Loader

Comment: ugh! now it's even worse... the repeating swf is back, the movie doesn't even load at all now, only the audio. Fortunately I have the previous version. Can I send you the current code?

Comment: it's too long to list here.

Comment: I think I'm going to post a new question so I can list the code;the previous version. I hope you are still able to help! If not, thanks anyway for all your efforts and have a good weekend.